# Haskell: applying a function with multiple arguments using Map

Tags: haskell

i want something like that:

helpPadNumbers ["123","45","1"] 4

the result should be: ["#123","##45","###1"] 
instead of '#' it should be ' ' (space) 
After my method all elements have the same length.

```
helpPadNumbers :: [String] -> Int -> [String]
helpPadNumbers x 0 = x
helpPadNumbers x a = map ((test1 x a) a)

test1 :: String -> Int -> String
test1 x a = (spaces1 ((a-length x))) ++ x

spaces1 :: Int -> String
spaces1 0 = ""
spaces1 n = " " ++ spaces1 (n-1)
```

My problem is: How can i get every single element of the list separately with the map function?

Error: "Probable cause: ‘map’ is applied to too few arguments"

is there a way to fix that problem?

Answer (score 9):

You are on the right track there - `map` does indeed what you want.
So let's start with a working version for a quick answer:

```
helpPadNumbers :: [String] -> Int -> [String]
helpPadNumbers x 0 = x
helpPadNumbers x a = map (\ xs -> test1 xs a) x
```

have a look at the map there - your problem was basically the order and the parens.

#### making it look nicer

Of course that's not really Haskell style so let's reorder your arguments a bit (and remove some parens):

```
helpPadNumbers :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
helpPadNumbers 0 xs = xs
helpPadNumbers a xs = map (test1 a) xs

test1 :: Int -> String -> String
test1 a x = spaces1 (a - length x) ++ x

spaces1 :: Int -> String
spaces1 0 = ""
spaces1 n = " " ++ spaces1 (n-1)
```

as you can see this version make use of partial application and we don't need the lambda-expression in there. Also it looks nicer IMO

#### `(++)` is not your friend

Have a look at `space1` - all you do is prepend a single space character but using lists and cocatenation - not really needed:

```
spaces1 :: Int -> String
spaces1 0 = ""
spaces1 n = ' ' : spaces1 (n-1)
```

as you can see this one uses `(:)` to prepend a single space character `' '` which is more performant.

Speaking of `space1`: there already is a function for this: [`replicate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate):

```
spaces1 :: Int -> String
spaces1 n = replicate n ' '
```

#### some further simplifications

`replicate` is rather forgiving (no problem with negative numbers or zero) - we don't really need the case where `a = 0` above. So we can simplify further to this:

```
helpPadNumbers :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
helpPadNumbers n xs = map (test1 n) xs

test1 :: Int -> String -> String
test1 n x = spaces1 (n - length x) ++ x

spaces1 :: Int -> String
spaces1 n = replicate n ' '
```

and I think we can fit the helper functions into a where clause:

```
helpPadNumbers :: Int -> [String] -> [String]
helpPadNumbers n = map spaces
  where spaces xs = replicate (n - length xs) ' ' ++ xs
```

example:

here is an example-use of the last version:

```
λ> helpPadNumbers 4 ["12345", "1234","123","12","1",""]
["12345","1234"," 123","  12","   1","    "]
```

Comment: Thank you! I see i have to work on my style in haskell!

Comment: no problem - it's really just a few transformations that are rather mechanical - just get your head around the types, currying and partial application - the rest will follow. BTW: some might argue my style too (some like point-free, some like it explicit, ...)

Comment: I like your approach: start with a simple fix to get the working version, then optimize (w/ explanations) until you arrive at the desired form.  You're not just showing the final code, you're showing the entire path to get there.  Great job!